# Magento 2.3.3 Database ERD

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I want to understand Magento's database tables to come up with some insights. I got hold of [this](https://anna.voelkl.at/uploads/magento/ce1922.png) but this is old. Hence, I'm looking for a Magento 2.3.3 database ERD.

Answer (score 0):

I only found this one for M2.1.3

https://anna.voelkl.at/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ce2.1.3.png